# How to use an Arduino as an emulator to filter signals?

Tags: arduino-uno

[image: Simulink Model]

What should be the Arduino code to emulate it as a 3rd order IIR filter?

Comment: the picture is the simulink model

Comment: Do I smell homework? What did you try? What problem you had?

Comment: The Arduino code would be whatever the C code would be. I'm sure you can find some C code examples online...

Comment: that is a badly drawn diagram ..... there is no reason why any of the lines should cross

Comment: The Wikipedia page [Digital filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter) shows how to derive the difference equation from the transfer function H(z), and how to practically implement it.